# Get message id (not universal id) from Notes document

Tags: email, lotus-notes, messageid

I want to fetch message id of the document. I tried

```
document.getItemValueString("$MessageID");
```

but it's giving null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this thread from the Notes forum.  You may need to follow the advice there, which is to set the [saveMessageOnSend](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/lotusscript/lotusscript.nsf/1efb1287fc7c27388525642e0074f2b6/51d7c38d3b9b99c68525642e007702e4?OpenDocument) property to true before sending and then obtain the `$MessageID` from the copy of the document that is saved back to the mail database.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/78d8a01e181f9b73852569fa0078668a/f08a0ebfc65537b185257b4300097939?OpenDocument

Otherwise, you may need to add a tilde before the dollar sign:

```
document.getItemValueString("~$MessageID");
```

Comment: I am not sure if you *need* to put a `~` sign in the statement `document.getItemValueString("~$MessageID");`. Have a look at this line number 466 in [this XSnippet](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=reverse-engineering-notes-apps-sample-code). It does it without the `~` sign.